# Powershell issue extracting primary SMTP while having multiple smtps

Tags: powershell, directory

Was looking around and found this little powershell script. BAsically want to be able to export all my primary SMTP and username from AD.

`Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties proxyaddresses | Select-Object Name, @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = {($_.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -like "*SMTP:*" }) -join ';'} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\mohammad.anwar\Documents\proxyaddresses.csv -NoTypeInformation`

The output would give me multiple smtp. Im looking for the Primary SMTP.

Comment: Use `-clike` instead

Comment: Sorry, where would i use -clike?

Comment: I also tried this Get-ADUser –Filter * –Properties proxyaddresses | Select-Object Name, @{L = “ProxyAddresses”; E = { $_.ProxyAddresses -join “;”}} | Export-Csv –Path c:\temp\proxyaddresses.csv –NoTypeInformation. Same result

Comment: the PRIMARY address is always supposed to be listed with `SMTP` instead of `smtp`. so you MUST test for that in all upper case. that is what `AdminOfThings` means by using `-clike` instead of `-like` in your `Where-Object` filter.

Comment: When I add -clike and when i run it all i see is ">>" any suggestions why this is happening?

Comment: @NCRIMTL - what happens if you do `$Test = Get-ADUser -Filter 'YourUserName' -Properties proxyaddresses` and then do `$Test | Select-Object -Property *`? do you see any values? you SHOULD see at least one `SMTP:YourUserName@YourDomainName.YourTDL` ...

Comment: @NCRIMTL - in order for your msg to get to whomever you want to see it ... start if off with an `@` symbol and then the StackOverflow user name.

Comment: @NCRIMTL if you are seeing `>>` that means you either didn't close a `(`, `{`, or a quote properly. You need a second `}` after `-join ';'}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of your query is fairly sound. There are just some syntax and operator issues with producing the result you want.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties ProxyAddresses |
    Select-Object Name, @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = {($_.ProxyAddresses -clike "SMTP:*") -join ';'}} |
        Export-Csv -Path C:\proxyaddresses.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Most PowerShell [Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) are case-insensitive. The case-sensitive operators begin with `-c`. `-clike` should be used instead of `-like` when case matters.

Since `ProxyAddresses` will be a collection, you don't need `Where-Object` (if running PowerShell 3+). You can just compare the `ProxyAddresses` values directly. PowerShell will enumerate the collection.

I honestly can't think of a case where an account would have multiple primary SMTP addresses (the `SMTP:` address). So having a `-join` doesn't make much sense since `-join` attempts to join items of a ***resulting*** collection. If you want to query all SMTP addresses (including lowercase `smtp:`) for an account, then `-join` would make sense here.

In your attempt, you will see `>>` when the code is run at the console. The reason is because you did not close all of your open `{`. The hash table for the `Select-Object` calculated property (begins with `@{`) was never closed. The PowerShell console has this behavior when an opening `(`, `{`, or quote is not closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

This is a very common thing with plenty of examples all over the web showing how to do this. Why do this from ADDS vs native Exchange cmdlets to get this info by default.

> [You can use remoting to get the Exchange cmdlets for use via your
>   workstation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/connect-to-exchange-servers-using-remote-powershell?view=exchange-ps)

Of course, searching for 'PowerShell get primary SMTP address' delivers examples for Exchange native and ADDS options.

Examples:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | 
Select-Object SamAccoutnName, DisplayName, PrimarySmtpAddress

# Or this...
Get-Mailbox -Identity $UID | 
Select -ExpandProperty PrimarySmtpAddress


# Or via ADDS cmdlets or other
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(proxyAddresses=*)" -Properties sAMAccountName, proxyAddresses | 
Select sAMAccountName, proxyAddresses | 
ForEach {
    $Name = $User.sAMAccountname
    $Addresses = $User.proxyAddresses

    ForEach ($Address In $Addresses)
    {
        If ($Address -cmatch "SMTP:")
        {"User $Name has primary address $Address" }
    }
}
```

[Identify primary SMTP Address from Active Directory with PowerShell](https://itfordummies.net/2015/06/17/identify-primary-smtp-address-from-active-directory-with-powershell)

```
# First, we need to get the ProxyAddresses attribute from AD :
Get-ADUser -Identity SomeUserName -Properties ProxyAddresses | 
select -ExpandProperty ProxyAddresses

# Then, we need to identify the one that starts with “SMTP:” :
# We used the “clike” operators, which is case sensitive :
Get-ADUser -Identity SomeUserName -Properties ProxyAddresses | 
select -ExpandProperty ProxyAddresses | 
? {$_ -clike "SMTP:*"}
```